# How can I know the targets of JVM configuration?

Tags: java, jvm

How can I know the targets of JVM configuration?

I know how to set JVM for my server, which can be done by command

`'java -Xmx3550m -Xms3550m -Xmn2g -Xss128k'`.

But what's command can to see what it is like? Any guidance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use VisualVm/Jconsole to connect to your running jvm.  This will give you all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for advise and I will try do use these tools to meet my requires.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running linux you can use something like `ps -efx | grep java`

Comment: `jps -lvm` may be better choice and it works on Windows, Linux, Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

You can use VisualVM to display information about the JVM.

If you want to see the command line arguments you can use `jps -lvm` to list all your java processes.

The maximum size is a little suspect. It appear you are trying to pick the maximum size for a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS (which can be about 3.5 GB on some OSes)  Personally I would just use a 64-bit JVM and use 4 GB as this uses 32-bit references so there is very little disadvantage in doing so.